# High Log Send Q in AG server

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

We have 6 SQL Server cluster all are part of AG, 1 is primary server and 5 are secondary read replicas.

We are facing issue with High log Send Q size for specific database, we have 5 database in AG only one database is creating problem,

During the High High LoG sendQ observed RedoQ is very minimal, During this situation We observed below things.

- Log file size : 300 GB (84% occupied)
- Log_reuse_wait_desc  : REPLICATION
- CDC is enabled in the database.
- Transaction replication is set on the database.

No long running transaction observed.

Can one any help me to find out exact root cause?

Due to this issue our readable replication server behind from primary.

Comment: Can you try running [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/) on the problematic server (and/or the one with Replication enabled) and update your question with the results? It may lead you to the source of your issue.

Comment: [CDC uses the Log Reader Agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replicate-track-change-data-capture-always-on-availability?view=sql-server-ver15#CDC), so the `REPLICATION` log reuse wait could be related to CDC. Have you checked that the CDC log reader is up to date?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? What do the wait stats look like?

Comment: Hi AMtwo,

How to check the CDC log reader is update to date or not, during that time some CDCCapture job running, and non business hours CDCCleanupjob is running.

Comment: Hi David, 
Version of SQL server is 2016 Enterprise edition and we have 5 readable replica,
The database having issue having CDC enabled and Transaction replication also configured.

Comment: What's the status of the replication log reader agent?

Comment: Status of log reader agent is running.